# aws cdk invoke shared yarn workspace dependency locally

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, yarn-workspaces

I am building a typescript project with AWS CDK.

I am trying to setup a backend where I have several lambda functions which share a common lib (which will ultimately talk to dynamo-db).

I created a very simple demo with one `hello-world` lambda importing from one common `my-lib` package (using yarn workspaces).
https://github.com/ziggy6792/aws-cdk-lambda-shared-package

If I deploy this stack to AWS and run my `hello-world` lambda (by testing from the AWS console) it works! (It successfully imports `my-lib` does not error).

However I can't mock my lambda function locally.

I have tried to use this method (which I found [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/aws-run-lambda-functions-built-with-cdk-locally-using-aws-sam)) to mock locally (this method works fine when I don't import my common `my-lib`).

- `cdk synth --no-staging > template.yml` (to find the logical lambda function id = `HelloWorldLambda5A02458E`)
- `sam local invoke HelloWorldLambda5A02458E`

But I get an error

```
{"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'my-lib/MyLib'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js"}
```

It seems `sam local invoke` is not aware of my yarn workspace dependency to `my-lib`

#### My question is

1. How I can test my lambda function locally (not being able to test locally is a deal breaker for me)?

Thanks a lot